Re render in swiper js
Does anyone know how to re-render the swipe in swipejs?
I'm filtering elements in the div list but the bullets are the same and also the width of the constainer is not catching up with my hide() of JQuery.
this is my init code:
 <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
      slidesPerView: 3,
      observer: true,
      observeParents: true,
      grid: {
        rows: 2,
      },
      spaceBetween: 30,
      pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        dynamicBullets: true,
        clickable: true,
      },
    });
  </script>

any ideas?
can't find how to re-render

Destroy and re-initialize the instance?

This question is similar to: destroy iDangerous Swiper if window is resized to a bigger resolution or call it when resized to a smaller resolution. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
